My android phone has 4 cameras - how does the app use the 4 cameras?
How does that work?
Also, is the app for a phone specially customized to do that - or if I use an alternative, like LMC8.4 (it doesn't have a special version for my particular phone), will it also see and use the wide-angle and telephoto cameras?
Finally, can I influence how the app uses the various cameras?
Thanks in advance!
FWIW, my current phone is a Uniherz Tank 3 Pro.
